# Pass a Pointer or Ref to the constructor of an object

Tags: c++, pointers, ref

Fairly new to C++ and having an issue with ref vs. pointer.  The code below is a class for a simple motor and works.  I would like to pass the pin expander in the constructor, but cannot seem to get that working.

I call the methods with &expander.  I tried adding a setter and getter for the expander but that did not seem to work.

Is this the best way, and can I pass it to the constructor?

This is the header

```
#ifndef PMotor_H
#define PMotor_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <PCF8575.h>

class PMotor {
private:

  uint8_t pinA;
  uint8_t pinB;
  uint8_t direction;


public:
  // Constructor
  PMotor(uint8_t pinA, uint8_t pinB);

  // Turn the motor on with a specified speed.
  void on(uint8_t direction, PCF8575 *expander);

  // Turn the motor on with a specified speed, for a given time.
  void on(uint8_t direction, int millisec, PCF8575 *expander);

  // Turn the motor off.
  void off(PCF8575 *expander);
  bool movingCW();
  bool movingCCW();


};

#endif
```

This is the CPP

```
#include "PMotor.h"
#include <PCF8575.h>

bool mCW;
bool mCCW;

PMotor::PMotor(uint8_t pinA, uint8_t pinB) {
  this->pinA = pinA;
  this->pinB = pinB;
}



void PMotor::on(uint8_t direction, PCF8575 *expander) {

  if (direction == 0) {
    expander->write(pinA, HIGH);
    expander->write(pinB, LOW);
    mCW = true;
    mCCW = false;

  } else {
    expander->write(pinA, LOW);
    expander->write(pinB, HIGH);
    mCW = false;
    mCCW = true;
  }
}

void PMotor::on(uint8_t direction, int millisec, PCF8575 *expander) {
  this->on(direction, expander);
  delay(millisec);
  this->off(expander);
}

void PMotor::off(PCF8575 *expander) {
  expander->write(this->pinA, LOW);
  expander->write(this->pinB, LOW);
  mCW = false;
  mCCW = true;
}

bool PMotor::movingCW() {
  return mCW;
}

bool PMotor::movingCCW() {
  return mCCW;
}
```

Comment: You can pass it to the constructor in exactly the same way as you are doing for all the other member functions. I am not sure what the question is. I don't see how this has anything to do with getters or setters. That said, if you assume the argument to not be a null pointer, it would be better to use a reference instead (because references should always refer to a valid object, while it is fine for a pointer to be a null pointer).

Comment: Stack Overflow Usage Note: Instead of writing *did not seem to work* or any variants, describe what happened and contrast it with what you expected to happen. If you got a compiler error or warning, reproduce the message completely and exactly as text and don't bother with the what you expected to happen part. Not getting an error's pretty much implied in that case.

Comment: "cannot seem to get that working" and "that did not seem to work" are not adequate descriptions of what when wrong when you tried.  The answers to your questions are trivially "yes" you can pass a pointer to the constructor, but the way you're doing it seems fine (possibly better) actually.  Storing a pointer opens up a can of worms about managing the lifetime of the object to which you are pointing.

Comment: Side note: If you're figuring out the language details, experiment on a PC or other computer where you have access to a full suite of debugging tools so you can see exactly what's happening. Once you have the logic figured out and working, then migrate to the hardware that's more difficult to work on. On the PC replace calls to interact with the target hardware with little functions, stubs, that just tell you what happened, like print "Turned on motor 1". When you migrate to the target, fill out the stubs with the real code.

Comment: Really appreciate the inputs.  For those of you concerned with how I asked the question and what was or was not included.  Make a note of my ID, and don't bother replying to my questions in the future.  If I knew what I did not know I would not be here.

Comment: don't take critisism as an offense. Its about letting you know how you can make your quesiton more answerable. Users make this comments because they want your question be more answerable. You want that too, no?

Comment: Generally prefer references over raw pointers when in doubt. But you'd better change other methods to use references instead of pointers too.  On embedded environments - due to lack of underlying library support - not using raw pointers seems unrealistic. But with enough template boilerplate, it is possible to get it done. Migration from raw pointers is a primary step towards building safe libraries; especially in the embedded ecosystem.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai    Thanks for the suggestion.  I posted all the code with a question about how to change the constructor.  What difference does it make what I have tried.  Does that change the way the compiler works?  The condescension on sites like this is palpable.

Comment: a raw pointer means that a `nullptr` is valid input, but in your functions it is not valid to pass a `nullptr`

Comment: I dont see any condescension here. You ask,we try to help. Its natural that this involves you knowing less than those that try to help.

Comment: We can agree to disagree.

Comment: _"What difference does it make what I have tried"_ - That makes it easier for us to help you.  If you say, "I tried this and that", we may see the mistakes you made when trying it out and can suggest a correction. It also shows effort - and it's always good to show that some effort has been made and people are more likely to answer such questions. In your example, I see no reason to take pointers in the `on`/`off` overloads. They don't check if it's `nullptr` so take `PCF8575` by reference.

Comment: cont.  If you want to _store_ a reference to the expander in your `PMotor` then take it by reference, but store a pointer to make moving and copying a `PMotor` easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to pass the pin expander in the constructor, but cannot seem to get that working.

Here's one way that involves taking the expander by reference but storing a pointer. Taking it by reference makes sure that you don't get a `nullptr` - and storing it as a pointer makes it easy to add copy/move semantics to your class.

```cpp
class PMotor {
private:
    PCF8575* expander; // store a pointer
    uint8_t pinA;
    uint8_t pinB;
    uint8_t direction;

public:
    // Constructor - takes an expander by reference:
    PMotor(PCF8575& expander, uint8_t pinA, uint8_t pinB);

    // No expander needed in the rest:

    // Turn the motor on with a specified speed.
    void on(uint8_t direction);

    // Turn the motor on with a specified speed, for a given time.
    void on(uint8_t direction, int millisec);

    // Turn the motor off.
    void off();

    bool movingCW();
    bool movingCCW();
};
```

Then the implementation of the member functions can look pretty much like they already do - only with the `PCF8575*` argument removed.

The constructor would simply be:

```cpp
PMotor::PMotor(PCF8575& expander, uint8_t pinA, uint8_t pinB) :
    expander(&expander), // store the pointer
    pinA(pinA),
    pinB(pinB)
{}
```

If you would also like to have a setter and getter for the expander, it could look like this:

```cpp
class PMotor {
public:
    // ...

    // setter, sets a new expander and returns a reference to the old one
    PCF8575& Expander(PCF8575& new_expander) {
        PCF8575* old_expander = expander;
        expander = &new_expander;
        return *old_expander;
    }

    // getters for the expander
    PCF8575& Expander() { return *expander; }
    const PCF8575& Expander() const { return *expander; }

    // ...
};
```